# Visual Studio 2019: Builds succeed even if Content files are missing

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2019

I have a project in Visual Studio 2019 and I met a situation, when there were files with `Build Action` set to `Content` missing on a disk but present in project (listed in `.csproj` file). My local build finished successfully, but when I checked this code to TFS, build on the server failed because of missing files.

I wonder if there is any instrument to force VS compiler to look at Content files and check if they exist.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at the Visual Studio Plugin [Show Missing Files 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidGardiner.ShowMissing2019).

Disclaimer: I do not have any experience with this plugin myself, it just seems to fit your situation.